# SFML sf::RenderWindow::createWindow() crashes program

Tags: crash, window, visual-studio-2015, sfml

So I've been learning C++ and I've been trying to learn some SFML 2 via some videos. At first I had no real issues, I was using MS VS2012 and everything was fine. I start using MS VS2015 Community and it all starts going wrong and I've got no idea why!

**Main problem:**

Everything compiles, but it just crashes when I try to use sf::RenderWindow::createWindow()

**Error Message:**

I get the message "SFML_Project.exe is no longer working",
I go to debug it and it gives me the following message:

*Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
this->_Ptr was 0xCCCCCCCC.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

and it does it on this function (some SFML code I know nothing about)

```
const facet *_Getfacet(size_t _Id) const
    {   // look up a facet in locale object
    const facet *_Facptr = _Id < _Ptr->_Facetcount
        ? _Ptr->_Facetvec[_Id] : 0; // null if id off end  <- ON THIS LINE OF CODE IT BREAKS
    if (_Facptr != 0 || !_Ptr->_Xparent)
        return (_Facptr);   // found facet or not transparent
    else
        {   // look in current locale
        locale::_Locimp *_Ptr = _Getgloballocale();
        return (_Id < _Ptr->_Facetcount
            ? _Ptr->_Facetvec[_Id]  // get from current locale
            : 0);   // no entry in current locale
        }
    }
```

Line of info that was given at the Call Stack

> sfml-system-d-2.dll!std::locale::_Getfacet(unsigned int _Id) Line 451   C++

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "WindowName");

    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    texture.loadFromFile("Player.png");
    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    sf::Event eventHandler;
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(eventHandler))
        {
            switch(eventHandler.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

**SFML version:** Visual C++ 14 (2015) - 32-bit

**Project Properties:**

Debug -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories:

- $(SolutionDir)/SFML-2.3.2/include

Debug -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories:

- $(SolutionDir)/SFML-2.3.2/lib

Debug -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:

- sfml-main-d.lib
- sfml-window-d.lib
- sfml-graphics-d.lib
- sfml-system-d.lib
- sfml-network-d.lib
- sfml-audio-d.lib

**What I've tried:**

I've tried turning all the dependencies from sfml-XX-d.lib to sfml-XX.lib files, which does allow me to create a window and draw shapes to that window, but then when I try to use sf::Texture::loadFromFile("filename") the console command window turns into the matrix and starts beeping.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you link the window lib before the graphics lib.

Try to move up the window lib under the graphics lib.

```
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
```

If it's still crashing, it may because your sfml's dlls does not match the current sfml version that you have. Happened to me once, I downloaded a new version of sfml without updating the binaries.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it, I've tried changing the d.lib positions around, but nothing different is happening.